# Conditional Expectation with two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I have two normally distributed independent variables $A\sim N(m,v)$ and $B\sim N(n,w)$. I would like to compute the following conditional expectation:

$E[A | c*A+B\geq 0].$

I cannot find an approach to this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You cannot compute this. Some information on independence or correlation coefficient is needed for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply, the random variables are independent.

Answer (score 0):

I may have made some typographical errors but I think you have have $cA \sim \mathcal N(cm, c^2 v)$ and $cA+B \sim \mathcal N(cm+n, c^2 v + w)$

[You can then say](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/intuitive-explanation-of-contribution-to-sum-of-two-normally-distributed-random) with some tidying up $$\mathbb E[A \mid cA + B=d] = \frac{mw +cvd - n c v}{c^2 v + w}$$

Now if $D \sim \mathcal N(cm+n, c^2 v + w)$ then $\mathbb E[D \mid D \gt 0] = cm+n +\dfrac{\phi\left(\frac{-cm-n}{\sqrt{c^2 v + w}}   \right)}{1-\Phi\left(\frac{-cm-n}{\sqrt{c^2 v + w}}   \right)}\sqrt{c^2 v + w} $  which would make

$$\mathbb E[A \mid cA + B \gt 0] = m + \frac{cv}{\sqrt{c^2 v + w}}\dfrac{\phi\left(\frac{-cm-n}{\sqrt{c^2 v + w}}   \right)}{1-\Phi\left(\frac{-cm-n}{\sqrt{c^2 v + w}}   \right)}$$